# How to find information about Samsung firmware?

Tags: samsung, device-firmware

As I'm working as a mobile software technician, a lot of times I need to unpack some Odin firmware to add or remove some files, maybe adding some languages which aren't available in the firmware, then I repack it again so I can flash it with Odin. Thus, I need to understand Samsung firmware structure, I need to know how exactly the system works.

For example, Samsung Galaxy S III I747 is a US phone which comes with only 3 languages. If I want to add some other languages to its firmware, then I need to understand the CSC tree first, so I can edit it and add the desired languages pack.

I've been searching around for some tutorials about that but I couldn't find any. I know how to unpack and repack Odin files, but as I said, I need to understand the system.

Answer (score 3):

**[XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com/) is the go-to site for you**

- This link at XDA [Samsung Firmware Naming Convention](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1356325) would give you an insight into the conventions followed for **PDA,CSC and Phone, Region Codes,
  Year, Month, Revision codes and other useful references**

  - Depending upon the models you repair, you could search [XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com/) for **modem** related info including collection of modems for different regions
  - [Guide on repackaging firmware](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=965190)
  - [Samsung Firmware Version Number](http://ykkfive.blogspot.com/2012/02/samsung-firmware-version-number.html?m=1)
  - [Samsung Firmware Code Reference](http://ykkfive.blogspot.com/2011/11/samsung-firmware-code-reference.html?m=1)
  - [Editing CSC file](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1988202)
  - [Phone Info Samsung](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo) is a great tool to help you with many things related to Samsung phones. Quoting from the [developers thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=49394347) it would help you with

> SAMSUNG SPECIFIC:

- Phone Colour (Samsung specific)
- CSC Product Code (Samsung specific)
- CSC Sales Code (Samsung specific)
- Country Region (Samsung specific)
- RIL Serial Number (Samsung specific)
- PDA Version (Samsung specific)
- CSC Version (Samsung specific)
- Changelist (Samsung specific)
- Country of Origin ★ (Samsung specific)
- Phone Manufacturing Date ★ (Samsung specific)
- Knox Warranty Void ★ (Samsung specific)

> OTHER INFO:

- Manufacturer
- Phone Model
- Device Name
- Product Name
- IMEI
- Serial No
- Bootloader Version
- Baseband Version
- Kernel Version
- Build Number
- Build Description
- Fingerprint
- Build Date
- Android Version
- Mobile Operator Name/Mobile Network Code
- Total RAM, Screen size and resolution, Battery capacity and health