# Unbricking a Samsung A40

Tags: samsung, rooting, twrp, unbricking

I used Heimdall and I can't really finish flashing anything because I get this error "Error failed to send end session packet".

I also got the cyan screen saying "An error has occurred while updating the device software. Use the Emergency recovery function in the Smart Switch PC software".

I also get some red text a the top left of my screen that says "Custom Binary (Recovery) Blocked by OEM lock".

How to or where to find a Samsung A40 `userdata.img` file because I accidentally flashed the user data and not the recovery and now my phone is bricked?

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/samloader-download-updates-samsung-galaxy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Samsung S7 - Developer options not showing after build number pressed 7 times](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225021/samsung-s7-developer-options-not-showing-after-build-number-pressed-7-times)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Samsung 4 files(Repairing firmware) and Single firmware file for flashing?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141460/what-is-the-difference-between-samsung-4-filesrepairing-firmware-and-single-fi)

Comment: see also *"How to safely install TWRP"* and *"How to safely root"* from corsicanu @ xda (link behind RMM protection)

Comment: @alecxs Yes that is good but are you sure there is not a way where I can download the userdata.img file? If not to what partition should I flash the .md5 files to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to flash stock rom with Jodin3 on linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1561912/how-to-flash-stock-rom-with-jodin3-on-linux)

Comment: @alecxs Somewhat but I cannot seem to obtain the partition table.

Comment: Do you have Windows?

Comment: @ No I do not have Windows but I think I have an old laptop that was Windows installed on it.

Comment: Once you have downloaded, decrypted and extracted that files from samloader, select it into correlated slots according to it's prefixes and flash all together  *BL_\*.tar.md5
AP_\*.tar.md5
CP_\*.tar.md5
CSC_\*.tar.md5*

Comment: @alecxs I do know that but Jodin3 keeps asking for a partition table and it keeps giving me this error when I try to get it:                                                                
                                                            libusb: error [op_set_interface] setintf failed error -1 errno 71 ERROR: Setting up interface failed! Releasing device interface...

Comment: That is probably telling you unable to read partition table from device because of failed connection. update heimdall v1.4.2

Comment: @alecxs Thank you,  I updated Heimdall and typed  sudo heimdall print-pit and that rebooted my phone.

Comment: according to [JOdin3](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2598203) instructions reboot is expected. never used, maybe one must keep holding Vol Dn + Home while device reboots