# Will flashing the stock firmware using HOME_CSC instead of CSC restore all app settings?

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop, unbricking, device-firmware, csc

Will flashing the stock firmware using `HOME_CSC` instead of `CSC` restore all app settings, specifically the encrypted configuration file `/data/system/packages.xml`?

Motivation: If an unrooted Android device is soft-bricked by accidentally uninstalling critical system apps from user space (and hence modifying `packages.xml`), is there any practical way of restoring the secured `packages.xml` file to the stock version without wiping all data?

*UPDATE:* There is some additional confusion. It seems unclear what exactly `pm uninstall` from the ADB shell does, i.e. which files get modified (see [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/pm-uninstall-k.4427021/) and [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/q-pm-disable-wheres-it-store-the-list.2379517/)). Is it `packages.xml` or `package-restrictions.xml` or both?

Comment: Devices I know have one user data partition. Flashing this partition is equivalent to performing a factory reset.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137197/discussion-on-answer-by-alecxs-halp-soft-bricked-a40-after-uninstalling-apps-a).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Samsung 4 files(Repairing firmware) and Single firmware file for flashing?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141460/what-is-the-difference-between-samsung-4-filesrepairing-firmware-and-single-fi)

Comment: @alecxs Again, very informative, but not sure it actually answers my question (which refers to the installed/uninstalled/disabled state of apps)

Comment: Cleaned up comments - however, the answer remains the same as the linked solution does not apply here.